# Passing data between siblings | React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, mobx, siblings

I have a problem in React Native where i want to share an array between 2 sibling components. My app has a bottom navigation navigator, and in that I've defined the components to navigate between:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import MapScreen from './modules/Map';
import ProfileScreen from './modules/Profile';
import EventsScreen from './modules/Events';

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Events: {
      screen: EventsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="md-bookmark" color={tintColor} size={24} />
        )
      }
    },
    Map: {
      screen: MapScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="md-map" color={tintColor} size={24} />
        )
      }
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
          <Icon name="md-person" color={tintColor} size={24} />
        )
      }
    }
  }
);
```

The components that I want to communicate between is the MapScreen and the EventsScreen. I have an array in the MapScreen with markers that I want to be able to access from the EventsScreen. I've looked into both Redux and MobX, however from what I've read you would pass the array to both components through a parent, like the following in both MobX and Redux:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Sibling1 array={array}/>
        <Sibling2 array={array}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

However in my example the components don't share a parent apart from the bottom navigator, but I can't seem to pass variables to the components through that.

Is there any way for me to access the same array from both components?

Comment: redux seems a good way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using react-navigation you can pass the same prop to multiple screen by passing the `screenProps` property to your Navigator component :

e.g :

```
const Navigator = createBottomTabNavigator({});
...
<Navigator screenProps={{ array: arrayToPassToAllScreen }} />
Now you can access the 'array' prop in every screen by doing so : `this.props.screenProps.array`
```

**UPDATE** :

Here is what you need in the doc: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props

Answer (score 1):

You must have state placed somewhere "above" these two components. This can be done either through common parent which holds that specific peace of state and is providing this state to children through props, or you can use "global" solution like React context, Redux or any other state management library.